# Ionic 2 - Base 64 image not displayed when taking picture

Tags: ionic-framework, camera, ionic2, getpicture

This ones had me scratching my head for a few hours and its driving me insane now.

When I click the 'Take Picture' button, the camera opens as expected, but the imageData that gets returned does not display in the app.

**Take Picture HTML**

```
<ion-item (click)="takePicture()">
  Take Picture
  <ion-icon item-right name="camera"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

**Display Pictures HTML**

```
<img *ngFor="let image of images" [src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + image">
```

**Take Picture Method**

```
images: string[] = [];

takePicture() {
  Camera.getPicture({
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    targetWidth: 1000,
    targetHeight: 1000
  })
  .then(imageData => {
    this.images.push(imageData);
  });
}
```

**Error in App**
[image: Array has data. It's just broken :(]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from the Ionic forum and this worked for me. Still not sure why my code wasn't working...

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{image}}"
```